# Why aren't escape characters working for replace all brackets?

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I'm trying to replace all brackets with their opposite facing bracket as my take of solving the coding challenge on Hackerrank.com found [here.](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-balanced-brackets/problem)

I think have a solution to the challenge, but I can't seem to get the replace all function to work properly on my function. I've tried using `Pattern.quote(String)` as well as the escape backslashes, but for some reason my brackets are not being replaced.

```
public class Solution {

    public static boolean isBalanced(String expression) {

        if(expression.length() %2 != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {

            int middle = expression.length() /2;
            String open = expression.substring(0,middle);
            String close = expression.substring(middle);

            close.replaceAll("\\)", "\\(");
            close.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("}"),"{");
            close.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("]"), "[");
            new StringBuilder(close).reverse().toString();

            if(close.equals(open))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        for (int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++) {
            String expression = in.next();
            System.out.println( (isBalanced(expression)) ? "YES" : "NO" );
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I tested the code with a print statement after the line `new StringBuilder(close).reverse().toString();`

**Input:**

```
3
{[()]}
{[(])}
{{[[(())]]}
```

**Output:**

```
)]}
NO
])}
NO
))]]}}
NO
```

Comment: I tested it using print statements. The String does not change at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` objects in Java are immutable, so executing a replace command on one will not change the source `String`, but rather returns a new `String` that has been modified.

make your lines like this

```
close.replaceAll("\\)", "\\(");
```

instead look like this

```
close = close.replaceAll("\\)", "\\(");
```

to update the value of the `close` variable with a modified `String` object.

---

Likewise, the `String` being created here is being assigned to nothing and will be discarded:

```
new StringBuilder(close).reverse().toString();
```

You need to assign the created `String` somewhere, like

```
close = new StringBuilder(close).reverse().toString();
```

Comment: I can't believe I made such a silly mistake. Thanks for catching it!

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is fundamentally wrong, because it is prone to false positives.

Specifically, this string will produce a `"YES"`, while the string is clearly unbalanced:

```
[({{(]
```

After you split the string in half you will have `"[({"` and `"{(]"`. After replacing characters in the closing part you will have `"{(["`, which becomes `"[({"` after reversal. The result of transformation matches the first half of the string, so your code would incorrectly conclude that brackets inside string are matched.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the challenge! I'd still like to figure out why my code won't return true in any case though.